# GAE is slow (take 20 sec) processing /* web.xml filter or servlets

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web.xml

I want to server my clients on an url like `/@dmitry`. These request have no static URI, so I need to serve it dynamically.

Google App Engine takes about 20 seconds for each `/*` request.

I am using Java. I have in *web.xml*:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have tried also `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` and `<filter-mapping>` with `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`.

I want these request to perform fast.

You can see how slow this is http://www.mymarx.com/@dmitry

UPDATE:

Here is my code that get data from db. It requests instances by parent's key.

```
long accountId = TokenStore.store.load(token).getAccountId();
Query query = new Query(KIND, KeyFactory.createKey(AccountStore.KIND, accountId));
return datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

Comment: Care to explain what are you actually doing in that servlet? It seems that you are loading 800+ pieces of data from datastore? Are you doing it in a loop one-by-one?

Comment: In addition to doing lots of work on each request are instances starting to service these requests ?

Comment: Peter Knego, you are right. I will try use MemCache now.